# How can I insert into SQL Server upon inserting into MS Access?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am using MS Access to add data to datasheets.

How can I insert the data into SQL Server automatically, after inserting it into MS Access?

Comment: Are the tables in Access [LINKED tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797)?

Comment: Bring the sql server table in as a link table, then when you insert to the access table (the link table) it will be inserted into the SQL Server.